# Is non-dynamic scalar subquery evaluted for each row?

Tags: postgresql, optimization, cte, explain, postgresql-10

Is a scalar subquery that's independent on parent query (does not refer to the parent table) evaluated only once, or for each row, regardless?

```
SELECT /* ... */
FROM
    t1
WHERE
    parent = (
        -- is this sq evaluated once?
        SELECT
            t2.id
        FROM t2
        WHERE t2.id = 10
    )
```

or using a CTE

```
WITH parent_id AS (
    SELECT
        t2.id
    FROM t2
    WHERE t2.id = 10
)
SELECT /* ... */
WHERE
    parent = (
        SELECT p.id FROM parent_id p -- is this sq evaluated once?
    )
```

If the answer is that the subquery/CTE is evaluated for each row, would joining the CTE on each row improve the performance?

```
WITH parent_id AS (
    SELECT
        t2.id
    FROM t2
    WHERE t2.id = 10
)
SELECT /* ... */
FROM
    t1, parent_id
WHERE
    parent = parent_id.id
```

Also, is there a way to figure out from `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` how many times an expression was evaluated?

Note: the examples are arbitrary and do not reflect real scenario, thus ignore the fact it doesn't make sense to do a subquery to find out an `id` which is already known (`10`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is evaluated once.

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE` will display lines like these:

> ```
> ...
> InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
>     ->  Index Scan using t2_pkey on t2 (cost=0.29..5.31 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.024..0.025 rows=1 loops=1)
>           Index Cond: (id = 10)
> ...
> ```

`loops=1` tells you the subplan has only been evaluated *once*. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/using-explain.html#USING-EXPLAIN-ANALYZE)

> In some query plans, it is possible for a subplan node to be executed
>   more than once. For example, the inner index scan will be executed
>   once per outer row in the above nested-loop plan. In such cases, the
>   `loops` value reports the total number of executions of the node, [...]

With a *correlated* subquery like:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT id FROM t2 WHERE id = t1.parent_id) AS t2_id
FROM   t1;
```

(or something more useful) you would see `loops=`*`n`*,  where *`n`* is the number of rows `t1`.

Comment: yes, the manual quote explains why I'm seeing `loops=2` in the `Seq Scan on t2` [in here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/48d3b/14) (though it's scanning 4 rows... also seems to happen only for `IN` operator)